# Rails 5.1: Primary Key is not a BIGINT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

Using `rails 5.1.beta1` and `mysql2`, migrations *should* use `BIGINT` as primary key integers by [default](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26266).

Still my *primary keys are all 4-bit integers*.

---

**Example:**

*db/migrate/20170311112129_create_receipts.rb*

```
class CreateReceipts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :receipts do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Trying to set a `BIGINT` like `5473508900871246157` as `id`, Rails raises the following exception:

> ActiveModel::RangeError: 5473508900871246157 is out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4 bytes

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for that table describe it as?

Comment: That was something that threw me off when I encountered the issue. My database used the `BIGINT` datatype. After upgrading `rails` to `5.1.0.rc1` it works - seems like there have been some problems with `ActiveRecord`. I've had extensive discussions [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28386) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28575)

Answer (score 3):

Primary Keys are still 4 byte integers in Rails 5.1.beta1 as it was not reproducible on master. However if you want to set BigInt i.e 8 bytes unsigned value then you can attempt the following ways:

**case1:** If you have not migrated or you don't have data in the table. For specific table you can use:

```
class CreateReceipts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :receipts, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :id, :limit => 8
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**case 2:** You have already migrated and don't want to loose data.
In this case you can add new migration.

```
rails g migration change_primary_key_to_bigint_on_receipts
```

and in the migration file generated add

```
def change
  change_column :receipts, :id, :bigint
end
```

I have tried this method in Rails 5.0.2 and 5.1.beta1 and in both versions it works fine.

**case 3:** You want to set default primary key as BigInt for every table you create and don't want to mess with migration files.
Add this to the bottom of your `config/environment.rb`

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
```

**Addition to case 2** You can also use `execute` method to change the Id type

```
def up
  execute('ALTER TABLE receipts MODIFY COLUMN id BIGINT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT')
end

def down
  raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
end
```

This is not supported by ActiveRecord. The Drawback of this method is that when you rollback the migration, ActiveRecord raises an error as it doesn't know how to revert it.

Comment: After upgrading `rails` to `5.1.0.rc1` it works fine - seems like there have been some problems with `ActiveRecord`. I've had extensive discussions [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28386) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28575)